# Contact Form does not meet the condition

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

I have this contact form in php with this features: name(required),email(required), phone(not required) and message(required).

Original code:

```
<?php
//contact form
function cs_theme_contact_form_shortcode($atts)
{
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "id" => "contact_form",
        "top_margin" => "none",
        "el_class" => ""
    ), $atts));

    $output = "";
    $output .= '<form class="contact-form ' . ($top_margin!="none" ? esc_attr($top_margin) : '') . ($el_class!="" ? ' ' . esc_attr($el_class) : '') . '" id="' . esc_attr($id) . '" method="post" action="#">
        <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner">
            <fieldset class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container">
                <div class="block">
                    <input class="text_input" name="name" type="text" value="' . esc_html__("Your Name *", 'carservice') . '" placeholder="' . esc_html__("Your Name *", 'carservice') . '">
                </div>
                <div class="block">
                    <input class="text_input" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_html__("Your Email *", 'carservice') . '" placeholder="' . esc_html__("Your Email *", 'carservice') . '">
                </div>
                <div class="block">
                    <input class="text_input" name="phone" type="text" value="' . esc_html__("Your Phone", 'carservice') . '" placeholder="' . esc_html__("Your Phone", 'carservice') . '">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container">
                <div class="block">
                    <textarea class="margin_top_10" name="message" placeholder="' . esc_html__("Message *", 'carservice') . '">' . __("Message *", 'carservice') . '</textarea>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner margin-top-30">
            <fieldset class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container">
                <p>' . __("We will contact you within one business day.", 'carservice') . '</p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container align-right">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="theme_contact_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . esc_attr($id) . '">
                <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner margin-top-20 padding-bottom-20">
                    <a class="more submit-contact-form" href="#" title="' . esc_html__("SEND MESSAGE", 'carservice') . '"><span>' . __("SEND MESSAGE", 'carservice') . '</span></a>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode("cs_contact_form", "cs_theme_contact_form_shortcode");

//visual composer
function cs_theme_contact_form_vc_init()
{
    vc_map( array(
        "name" => __("Contact form", 'carservice'),
        "base" => "cs_contact_form",
        "class" => "",
        "controls" => "full",
        "show_settings_on_create" => true,
        "icon" => "icon-wpb-layer-contact-form",
        "category" => __('Carservice', 'carservice'),
        "params" => array(
            array(
                "type" => "textfield",
                "class" => "",
                "heading" => __("Id", 'carservice'),
                "param_name" => "id",
                "value" => "contact_form",
                "description" => __("Please provide unique id for each contact form on the same page/post", 'carservice')
            ),
            array(
                "type" => "dropdown",
                "class" => "",
                "heading" => __("Top margin", 'carservice'),
                "param_name" => "top_margin",
                "value" => array(__("None", 'carservice') => "none", __("Page (small)", 'carservice') => "page-margin-top", __("Section (large)", 'carservice') => "page-margin-top-section")
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'textfield',
                'heading' => __( 'Extra class name', 'js_composer' ),
                'param_name' => 'el_class',
                'description' => __( 'If you wish to style particular content element differently, then use this field to add a class name and then refer to it in your css file.', 'js_composer' )
            )
        )
    ));
}
add_action("init", "cs_theme_contact_form_vc_init");

//contact form submit
function cs_theme_contact_form()
{
    ob_start();
    global $theme_options;

    $result = array();
    $result["isOk"] = true;
    if($_POST["name"]!="" && $_POST["name"]!=__("Your Name *", 'carservice') && $_POST["email"]!="" && $_POST["email"]!=__("Your Email *", 'carservice') && preg_match("#^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$#", $_POST["email"]) && $_POST["message"]!="" && $_POST["message"]!=__("Message *", 'carservice'))
    {
        $values = array(
            "name" => $_POST["name"],
            "phone" => ($_POST["phone"]!=__("Your Phone", 'carservice') ? $_POST["phone"] : ""),
            "email" => $_POST["email"],
            "message" => $_POST["message"]
        );
        if((bool)ini_get("magic_quotes_gpc"))
            $values = array_map("stripslashes", $values);
        $values = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $values);

        $headers[] = 'From: ' . $values["name"] . ' <' . $values["email"] . '>' . "\r\n";
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html';
        $subject = $theme_options["cf_email_subject"];
        $subject = str_replace("[name]", $values["name"], $subject);
        $subject = str_replace("[email]", $values["email"], $subject);
        $subject = str_replace("[phone]", $values["phone"], $subject);
        $subject = str_replace("[message]", $values["message"], $subject);
        $body = $theme_options["cf_template"];
        $body = str_replace("[name]", $values["name"], $body);
        $body = str_replace("[email]", $values["email"], $body);
        $body = str_replace("[phone]", $values["phone"], $body);
        $body = str_replace("[message]", $values["message"], $body);
        $body = str_replace("[form_data]", "", $body);

        if(wp_mail($theme_options["cf_admin_name"] . ' <' . $theme_options["cf_admin_email"] . '>', $subject, $body, $headers))
            $result["submit_message"] = __("Thank you for contacting us", 'carservice');
        else
        {
            $result["isOk"] = false;
            $result["error_message"] =  $GLOBALS['phpmailer']->ErrorInfo;
            $result["submit_message"] = __("Sorry, we can't send this message", 'carservice');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $result["isOk"] = false;
        if($_POST["name"]=="" || $_POST["name"]==__("Your Name *", 'carservice'))
            $result["error_name"] = __("Please enter your name.", 'carservice');
        if($_POST["email"]=="" || $_POST["email"]==__("Your Email *", 'carservice') || !preg_match("#^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$#", $_POST["email"]))
            $result["error_email"] = __("Please enter valid e-mail.", 'carservice');
        if($_POST["message"]=="" || $_POST["message"]==__("Message *", 'carservice'))
            $result["error_message"] = __("Please enter your message.", 'carservice');
    }
    $system_message = ob_get_clean();
    $result["system_message"] = $system_message;
    echo @json_encode($result);
    exit();
}
add_action("wp_ajax_theme_contact_form", "cs_theme_contact_form");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_theme_contact_form", "cs_theme_contact_form");
?>
```

So i want to make some changes and add more features like this: name(required),email(required), phone(required), address(required) and message(not required).

then i modified the code like this:

```
<?php
//contact form
function cs_theme_contact_form_shortcode($atts)
{
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "id" => "contact_form",
        "top_margin" => "none",
        "el_class" => ""
    ), $atts));

    $output = "";
    $output .= '<form class="contact-form ' . ($top_margin!="none" ? esc_attr($top_margin) : '') . ($el_class!="" ? ' ' . esc_attr($el_class) : '') . '" id="' . esc_attr($id) . '" method="post" action="#">
        <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner">
            <fieldset class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container">
            <div class="block">
                <input class="text_input" name="name" type="text" value="' . esc_html__("Nombre Completo *", 'carservice') . '" placeholder="' . esc_html__("Nombre Completo *", 'carservice') . '">
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <input class="text_input" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_html__("Correo Electronico *", 'carservice') . '" placeholder="' . esc_html__("Correo Electronico *", 'carservice') . '">
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <input class="text_input" name="phone" type="text" value="' . esc_html__("Número de Celular *", 'carservice') . '" placeholder="' . esc_html__("Número de Celular *", 'carservice') . '">
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <input class="text_input" name="address" type="text" value="' . esc_html__("Dirección *", 'carservice') . '" placeholder="' . esc_html__("Dirección *", 'carservice') . '">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container">
            <div class="block">
                <textarea class="margin_top_10" name="message" placeholder="' . esc_html__("Mensaje", 'carservice') . '">' . __("Mensaje", 'carservice') . '</textarea>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner margin-top-30">
        <fieldset class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container">
            <p>' . __("Contactaremos contigo lo más pronto posible.", 'carservice') . '</p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container align-right">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="theme_contact_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . esc_attr($id) . '">
            <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner margin-top-20 padding-bottom-20">
                <a class="more submit-contact-form" href="#" title="' . esc_html__("ENVIAR", 'carservice') . '"><span>' . __("ENVIAR", 'carservice') . '</span></a>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode("cs_contact_form", "cs_theme_contact_form_shortcode");

//visual composer
function cs_theme_contact_form_vc_init()
{
    vc_map( array(
        "name" => __("Contact form", 'carservice'),
        "base" => "cs_contact_form",
        "class" => "",
        "controls" => "full",
        "show_settings_on_create" => true,
        "icon" => "icon-wpb-layer-contact-form",
        "category" => __('Carservice', 'carservice'),
        "params" => array(
            array(
                "type" => "textfield",
                "class" => "",
                "heading" => __("Id", 'carservice'),
                "param_name" => "id",
                "value" => "contact_form",
                "description" => __("Please provide unique id for each contact form on the same page/post", 'carservice')
            ),
            array(
                "type" => "dropdown",
                "class" => "",
                "heading" => __("Top margin", 'carservice'),
                "param_name" => "top_margin",
                "value" => array(__("None", 'carservice') => "none", __("Page (small)", 'carservice') => "page-margin-top", __("Section (large)", 'carservice') => "page-margin-top-section")
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'textfield',
                'heading' => __( 'Extra class name', 'js_composer' ),
                'param_name' => 'el_class',
                'description' => __( 'If you wish to style particular content element differently, then use this field to add a class name and then refer to it in your css file.', 'js_composer' )
            )
        )
    ));
}
add_action("init", "cs_theme_contact_form_vc_init");

//contact form submit
function cs_theme_contact_form()
{
    ob_start();
    global $theme_options;

    $result = array();
    $result["isOk"] = true;
    if($_POST["name"]!="" && $_POST["name"]!=__("Nombre Completo *", 'carservice') && $_POST["email"]!="" && $_POST["email"]!=__("Correo Electronico *", 'carservice') && preg_match("#^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$#", $_POST["email"]) && $_POST["phone"]!="" && $_POST["phone"]!=__("Número de Celular", 'carservice') && preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$/", $_POST["phone"]) && $_POST["address"]!="" && $_POST["address"]!=__("Dirección *", 'carservice'))
    {
        $values = array(
            "name" => $_POST["name"],
            "phone" => $_POST["phone"],
            "email" => $_POST["email"],
            "address" => $_POST["address"],
            "message" => ($_POST["message"]!=__("Mensaje", 'carservice') ? $_POST["message"] : "")
        );
        if((bool)ini_get("magic_quotes_gpc"))
            $values = array_map("stripslashes", $values);
        $values = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $values);

        $headers[] = 'From: ' . $values["name"] . ' <' . $values["email"] . '>' . "\r\n";
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html';
        $subject = str_replace("[name]", $values["name"], $subject);
        $subject = str_replace("[email]", $values["email"], $subject);
        $subject = str_replace("[phone]", $values["phone"], $subject);
        $subject = str_replace("[address]", $values["address"], $subject);
        $subject = str_replace("[message]", $values["message"], $subject);
        $body = $theme_options["cf_template"];
        $body = str_replace("[name]", $values["name"], $body);
        $body = str_replace("[email]", $values["email"], $body);
        $body = str_replace("[phone]", $values["phone"], $body);
        $body = str_replace("[address]", $values["address"], $body);
        $body = str_replace("[message]", $values["message"], $body);
        $body = str_replace("[form_data]", "", $body);

        if(wp_mail($theme_options["cf_admin_name"] . ' <' . $theme_options["cf_admin_email"] . '>', $subject, $body, $headers))
            $result["submit_message"] = __("Gracias por preferirnos. :)", 'carservice');
        else
        {
            $result["isOk"] = false;
            $result["error_message"] =  $GLOBALS['phpmailer']->ErrorInfo;
            $result["submit_message"] = __("Lo siento, no podemos enviar el mensaje por el momento. :()", 'carservice');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $result["isOk"] = false;
        if($_POST["name"]=="" || $_POST["name"]==__("Nombre Completo *", 'carservice'))
            $result["error_name"] = __("Por favor ingrese su nombre completo.", 'carservice');
        if($_POST["email"]=="" || $_POST["email"]==__("Correo Electronico *", 'carservice') || !preg_match("#^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$#", $_POST["email"]))
            $result["error_email"] = __("Por favor ingresa un correo electronico válido.", 'carservice');
        if($_POST["phone"]=="" || $_POST["phone"]==__("Número de Celular *", 'carservice') || !preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$/", $_POST["phone"]))
            $result["error_phone"] = __("Por favor ingresa un número de celular válido.", 'carservice');
        if($_POST["address"]=="" || $_POST["address"]==__("Dirección *", 'carservice'))
            $result["error_address"] = __("Por favor tu dirección.", 'carservice');
    }
    $system_message = ob_get_clean();
    $result["system_message"] = $system_message;
    echo @json_encode($result);
    exit();
}
add_action("wp_ajax_theme_contact_form", "cs_theme_contact_form");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_theme_contact_form", "cs_theme_contact_form");
?>
```

The thing im trying to do is add some restrictions like this:
Name must be filled, if not then appear some message saying "please write your name"; the same thing with email ( both work on the original contact form and in the modified code). I tried the same thing with the phone (phone must contain only numbers, if not then appear some message saying "please write a valid number", but when i test and write "98231176a"  the message does not appear; and the same error happens with the address and obviously all the information is not sent to the admin email beacuse the phone is not valid.
I have little knowledge of php, if someone could help me please. thanks

Comment: Why are you mixing HTML with a function declaration? That should be in a view.

Comment: Sorry im new at this thing. All this code and others came with the theme that i buy

Comment: @March_one check my answer it may help

Answer (score 1):

Replace :

```
&& preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$/", $_POST["phone"])
```

with:

```
&& is_numeric($_POST['phone']);
```

and also :

```
|| !preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$/", $_POST["phone"])
```

with :

```
|| !is_numeric($_POST['phone']);
```

and you can also make a function inside : functions.php and pass the phone number to function and get true or false in return to see if its valid phone number or not like this:

```
function validatePhone($string) {
    $numbersOnly = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $string);
    $numberOfDigits = strlen($numbersOnly);
    if ($numberOfDigits == 7 or $numberOfDigits == 10) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

USE IT LIKE THIS:

```
validatePhone($_POST['phone'])
```

it will solve the problem of phone number and make it important to be numerical and not contain any alphabets

complete code :

```
<?php
//contact form
function cs_theme_contact_form_shortcode($atts)
{
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "id" => "contact_form",
        "top_margin" => "none",
        "el_class" => ""
    ), $atts));

    $output = "";
    $output .= '<form class="contact-form ' . ($top_margin!="none" ? esc_attr($top_margin) : '') . ($el_class!="" ? ' ' . esc_attr($el_class) : '') . '" id="' . esc_attr($id) . '" method="post" action="#">
        <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner">
            <fieldset class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container">
            <div class="block">
                <input class="text_input" name="name" type="text" value="' . esc_html__("Nombre Completo *", 'carservice') . '" placeholder="' . esc_html__("Nombre Completo *", 'carservice') . '">
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <input class="text_input" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_html__("Correo Electronico *", 'carservice') . '" placeholder="' . esc_html__("Correo Electronico *", 'carservice') . '">
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <input class="text_input" name="phone" type="text" value="' . esc_html__("Número de Celular *", 'carservice') . '" placeholder="' . esc_html__("Número de Celular *", 'carservice') . '">
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <input class="text_input" name="address" type="text" value="' . esc_html__("Dirección *", 'carservice') . '" placeholder="' . esc_html__("Dirección *", 'carservice') . '">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container">
            <div class="block">
                <textarea class="margin_top_10" name="message" placeholder="' . esc_html__("Mensaje", 'carservice') . '">' . __("Mensaje", 'carservice') . '</textarea>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner margin-top-30">
        <fieldset class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container">
            <p>' . __("Contactaremos contigo lo más pronto posible.", 'carservice') . '</p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container align-right">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="theme_contact_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . esc_attr($id) . '">
            <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner margin-top-20 padding-bottom-20">
                <a class="more submit-contact-form" href="#" title="' . esc_html__("ENVIAR", 'carservice') . '"><span>' . __("ENVIAR", 'carservice') . '</span></a>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode("cs_contact_form", "cs_theme_contact_form_shortcode");

//visual composer
function cs_theme_contact_form_vc_init()
{
    vc_map( array(
        "name" => __("Contact form", 'carservice'),
        "base" => "cs_contact_form",
        "class" => "",
        "controls" => "full",
        "show_settings_on_create" => true,
        "icon" => "icon-wpb-layer-contact-form",
        "category" => __('Carservice', 'carservice'),
        "params" => array(
            array(
                "type" => "textfield",
                "class" => "",
                "heading" => __("Id", 'carservice'),
                "param_name" => "id",
                "value" => "contact_form",
                "description" => __("Please provide unique id for each contact form on the same page/post", 'carservice')
            ),
            array(
                "type" => "dropdown",
                "class" => "",
                "heading" => __("Top margin", 'carservice'),
                "param_name" => "top_margin",
                "value" => array(__("None", 'carservice') => "none", __("Page (small)", 'carservice') => "page-margin-top", __("Section (large)", 'carservice') => "page-margin-top-section")
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'textfield',
                'heading' => __( 'Extra class name', 'js_composer' ),
                'param_name' => 'el_class',
                'description' => __( 'If you wish to style particular content element differently, then use this field to add a class name and then refer to it in your css file.', 'js_composer' )
            )
        )
    ));
}
add_action("init", "cs_theme_contact_form_vc_init");

//contact form submit
function cs_theme_contact_form()
{
    ob_start();
    global $theme_options;

    $result = array();
    $result["isOk"] = true;
    if($_POST["name"]!="" && $_POST["name"]!=__("Nombre Completo *", 'carservice') && $_POST["email"]!="" && $_POST["email"]!=__("Correo Electronico *", 'carservice') && preg_match("#^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$#", $_POST["email"]) && $_POST["phone"]!="" && $_POST["phone"]!=__("Número de Celular", 'carservice') && is_numeric($_POST['phone']) && $_POST["address"]!="" && $_POST["address"]!=__("Dirección *", 'carservice'))
    {
        $values = array(
            "name" => $_POST["name"],
            "phone" => $_POST["phone"],
            "email" => $_POST["email"],
            "address" => $_POST["address"],
            "message" => ($_POST["message"]!=__("Mensaje", 'carservice') ? $_POST["message"] : "")
        );
        if((bool)ini_get("magic_quotes_gpc"))
            $values = array_map("stripslashes", $values);
        $values = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $values);

        $headers[] = 'From: ' . $values["name"] . ' <' . $values["email"] . '>' . "\r\n";
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html';
        $subject = str_replace("[name]", $values["name"], $subject);
        $subject = str_replace("[email]", $values["email"], $subject);
        $subject = str_replace("[phone]", $values["phone"], $subject);
        $subject = str_replace("[address]", $values["address"], $subject);
        $subject = str_replace("[message]", $values["message"], $subject);
        $body = $theme_options["cf_template"];
        $body = str_replace("[name]", $values["name"], $body);
        $body = str_replace("[email]", $values["email"], $body);
        $body = str_replace("[phone]", $values["phone"], $body);
        $body = str_replace("[address]", $values["address"], $body);
        $body = str_replace("[message]", $values["message"], $body);
        $body = str_replace("[form_data]", "", $body);

        if(wp_mail($theme_options["cf_admin_name"] . ' <' . $theme_options["cf_admin_email"] . '>', $subject, $body, $headers))
            $result["submit_message"] = __("Gracias por preferirnos. :)", 'carservice');
        else
        {
            $result["isOk"] = false;
            $result["error_message"] =  $GLOBALS['phpmailer']->ErrorInfo;
            $result["submit_message"] = __("Lo siento, no podemos enviar el mensaje por el momento. :()", 'carservice');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $result["isOk"] = false;
        if($_POST["name"]=="" || $_POST["name"]==__("Nombre Completo *", 'carservice'))
            $result["error_name"] = __("Por favor ingrese su nombre completo.", 'carservice');
        if($_POST["email"]=="" || $_POST["email"]==__("Correo Electronico *", 'carservice') || !preg_match("#^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$#", $_POST["email"]))
            $result["error_email"] = __("Por favor ingresa un correo electronico válido.", 'carservice');
        if($_POST["phone"]=="" || $_POST["phone"]==__("Número de Celular *", 'carservice') || !is_numeric($_POST['phone']))
            $result["error_phone"] = __("Por favor ingresa un número de celular válido.", 'carservice');
        if($_POST["address"]=="" || $_POST["address"]==__("Dirección *", 'carservice'))
            $result["error_address"] = __("Por favor tu dirección.", 'carservice');
    }
    $system_message = ob_get_clean();
    $result["system_message"] = $system_message;
    echo @json_encode($result);
    exit();
}
add_action("wp_ajax_theme_contact_form", "cs_theme_contact_form");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_theme_contact_form", "cs_theme_contact_form");
?>
```

Comment: Then I replace the code you gave me also put the function inside functions.php but in the test when i write for example 12312312a does not appear the error message ("please write a valid number") and when i pass the mouse on the box phone, The pointer is loading. i dont know where to put the " validatePhone($_POST['phone']) ". you can test the contact form here: [contact form](http://aerocarwash.com/cita/) thanks

Comment: @March_one  check the answer edit i have made the changes to your code copy that and try that :)

Comment: thank you for answer. the page still have the same error (does not appear the error message ("please write a valid number")). when i left blank all the boxes only appear the message in name and email but not in phone and address. heres a ![pic](http://i1236.photobucket.com/albums/ff447/maxentiusII/Aero%20Car%20Wash%20and%20Detailing/error.png). Also when i send a normal message i just get the normal features (name ,email, phone and message) here a ![pic](http://i1236.photobucket.com/albums/ff447/maxentiusII/Aero%20Car%20Wash%20and%20Detailing/error3.png). thanks